# Python : MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up my website on a EC2 Amazon-Linux instance and it uses some Python.

After a lot of tuning I had big troubles setting up Python. 
Especially the following code throws an error:

```
 >>> import MySQLdb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.1020: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My instances setup is the following:

```
Python 2.7.12
MySql  5.7.18
```

Installing MySQL via pip went fine

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
Successfully installed MySQL-python-1.2.5
```

Sébastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux comes with `MySQL-python27` packages that you can install, if you're using the standard Python installation from the system.

I'd suggest removing your current one and installing the one provided via `yum`, like so:

```
sudo yum remove MySQL-python
sudo yum install MySQL-python27
```

Otherwise, you probably need to remove the module, install the MySQL 5.7 libs, and then reinstall the module.

```
sudo pip uninstall MySQL-python
sudo yum install mysql57-libs
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

There is also a pure Python implementation of a MySQL driver which is more actively maintained.

```
sudo pip install PyMySQL
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue. 2 small edits:  "sudo **yum** remove MySQL-python" && "sudo yum install MySQL-python27"